# Accessing COM server (EXE) remotely using Java (DCOM)

Tags: java, com, com-interop, dcom

I have a question about accessing COM objects remotely. Currently I am using JACOB to connect our custom COM server (exe) and it works really well. However we are trying to separate the Java code from the COM server and place them on separate machines. JACOB doesn't support DCOM. So I wanted to know is this possible with com4j? If so can you point to some links, etc. I have already tried using j-interop and hate it since it is extremely verbose and totally non-intuitive.

Also when I access the COM server's properties using the Component Services > DCOM+ Config what does the location tab option "Run Application on the following Computer"  mean? Does it mean that the computer selected must also have the COM Server (exe) on it? This would seem redundant.

Lastly are there any other free open source libraries out there that will allow the functionality I am trying to acheieve?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out j-interop proxy (https://github.com/kohsuke/jinterop-proxy), this makes j-interop calls a lot less verbose. You can find usage examples in the Hudson project.